# End user designer in crystal reports

Tags: c, crystal-reports

I want to provide the end users of my application an option to modify the crystal report after the report is loaded. How can I provide this option? I've googled for days but couldn't get any solution. What I found was to upgrade to professional edition of crystal report and use the Report Application Server(RAS), which is not an option for me since my client cannot afford to buy it. Is there a workaround for this? What I really want is to let the users delete the columns they don't need in the report, change the order of columns etc. Pls help.

With regards,
JosephJCKochi

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a designer control that I've seen.

Options:

- You could use a parameter to determine which fields are displayed and another parameter to control grouping.
- I would ask why people need to remove a field.  Why can they just ignore it?  You'll expend a lot of resources trying to meet this requirement.
- If they need to do 'additional analysis', I would ask what this means.  Is is a cross-tab?  A graph?  Flexible sorting or grouping?  Then just add it to the report.